Changing the speech_rate has no effect in Google TTS Journey
I have been successfully generating audio files from my text with the python code given below.
However now I want to slow down the speaking rate, but changing the speaking_rate to any value has no effect on the audio output.There are no errors. The audio file outputs fine. But it is the exact same everytime (i.e. speaking_rate is not working).
Is speaking_rate supported for en-US-Journey-O voice?
If not what voices can I use that sound natural and I can manipulate the speaking speed?
I've seen the exact same issue raised with no solution here:
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/speaking-rate-has-no-effect-for-Journey-Voice-in-Text-To-Speech/td-p/759770
Here is my code:
`def synthesize_text(text, output_file):
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
# Synthesize text output
input_text = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text=text)

# Voice parameters
voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code="en-US",
    name = "en-US-Journey-O"
)

# Set up the audio configuration (output format)
audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    speaking_rate = 0.5
)

# The text-to-speech request
response = client.synthesize_speech(
    input=input_text, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config
)

# Write the response (audio content) to the output file
with open(output_file, "wb") as out:
    out.write(response.audio_content)
print(f"Audio content written to {output_file}")`


I've found a alternative solution for now which is to use a different voice which supports speaking_rate changes.
name = "en-US-Studio-O"

According to https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voice-types:

Journey Voices doesn't support SSML input, speaking rate and pitch
audio parameters, and the A-Law audio encoding.

